# Best place in AWS for a long running subscription background service

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, background-process, aws-fargate

I currently am trying to set up a system in AWS that utilises EventSourcing & CQRS. I've got everything working on the Command side, and this is storing the events into Aurora. I've got SqlEventStore as my EventSourcing store and that has a Subscription mechanism that will listen for new events and then fire a function appropriately.

So far it's all set up in Lambda, but I can't have the subscription in Lambda as they aren't always running, so my first thought was running this side in Fargate and a docker container. Using my reading though, this seems to need to be fired by a task, rather than sit in the container on a subscription.

So my question is really, where is best to have a long running process in AWS that just sits listening for things to happen, rather than responding to a prod from something like a Lambda.

Comment: Why does the Lambda need to be always running, i.e. not an SQS queue that is an event source for Lambda and whenever a message is added to the queue, it serves as a trigger for Lambda to run?

Comment: Because the eventstore isn't SQS. The events get stored into a database - the third party library i'm using then has a subscription mechanism that would populate a read model

Comment: Ah gotcha, for my own edification, what is the 3rd party library you are using (assuming it's public)?

Comment: @AshamanKingpin sure it's https://github.com/SQLStreamStore/SQLStreamStore

Answer (score 2):

> So my question is really, where is best to have a long running process
>   in AWS that just sits listening for things to happen, rather than
>   responding to a prod from something like a Lambda.

I will suggest to go with [Fargate](https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/) or EC2 type ECS container, with fargate you do not need manage server, something similar to lambda but more suitable for such long-running process.

> This seems to need to be fired by a task, rather than sit in the
>   container on a subscription.

no, you can run fargate in two ways.

- Running as a long-running services
- fire service based on [cloud watch event or schedule time](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/APIReference/API_EcsParameters.html) ( perform task and terminate)

> AWS Fargate now supports the ability to run tasks on a regular,
>   scheduled basis and in response to CloudWatch Events. This makes it
>   easier to launch and stop container services that you need to run only
>   at certain times.

[AWS fargate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/AWS_Fargate.html)

> Where is best to have a long-running process in AWS that just sits
>   listening for things to happen, rather than responding to an event from something like a Lambda

- If your task is supposed for the run for a long time then lambda is not for you, there is always timeout in case of lambda.
- If you do not want to manage the server, and the process is supposed to run for a long time, then fargate is for you, so then it's fine to sit for the event and listen.

Comment: I was wondering about Fargate and putting the long running process in a docker container. I'll go give that a try, would be great if it can be managed using the Serverless Framework too!

Comment: the reason is you are expecting to run for a long time then definitely lambda will fail because of fo timeout behaviour

Comment: Yeah I know Lambda won't work because the context will die, hence why I'm searching for somewhere to put an open subscription

Comment: You can explore AWS another service too but I will prefer fargate. you have more control over the underlying system then lambda.

Answer (score 0):

you can explore aws glue python shell for long running server services.